# What instrument should I use in Xcode to see FPS?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, instruments, using, frame-rate

Some time ago I used instruments to see the FPS of an iPad application in Xcode 3. Now I'm using Xcode 4 and I can't find the correct instrument for viewing the FPS. What is it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was trying to view FPS on Simulator, on real device the list of instruments differs from the list of simulator ones. So I connect iPad to Mac, choose "Core Animation" instrument and get FPS.

Answer (score 0):

in an OpenGL app you can use in Instrument -> Graphics -> OpenGL Es Driver